# How to click on Search button under For Loop (Python Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am hoping that I can select all the stock in the drop down menu, hit the "Search" button and hit "Export to CSV" button. However, I am stuck that I am not able to hit the Search button after choosing the option. Please advise. Thank you

```
   from selenium import webdriver
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select, WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
   from time import ctime

   browser = webdriver.Chrome()
   browser.get("https://www.hkex.com.hk/eng/sorc/options/statistics_hv_iv.aspx")

   select = Select(WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,        
    "//select[@id='underlying']"))))


   browser.implicitly_wait(10)
   optionsList = []

   #iterate over the options, place attribute value in list
   for option in select.options:
       option.click()
       optionsList.append(option.get_attribute("value"))

       # below code is not able to work properly but this is only what I am hoping to work
       elem = browser.find_element_by_link_text("Search")
       elem.click()
       elem1 = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Export to CSV")
       elem1.click()
       print(elem)

   print(optionsList)
   print(len(optionsList))


   browser.quit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`()

While clicking on the `Export to CSV` button the page will refresh and it will be no longer available to the page and you will get stale exception.To avoid this you need to re-assign the element inside for loop.

**Code**:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select, WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://www.hkex.com.hk/eng/sorc/options/statistics_hv_iv.aspx")
browser.maximize_window()
select = Select(WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//select[@id='underlying']"))))
optionsList = []
items=select.options
for i in range(len(items)):
    #re-assigned select elements again to avoid stale exception
    select = Select(WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='underlying']"))))
    items = select.options
    print(items[i].get_attribute("value"))
    select.select_by_value(items[i].get_attribute("value"))
    optionsList.append(items[i].get_attribute("value"))
    #click on search button
    WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[@class='floatleft']//a[@title='Search']"))).click()
    #click on download button
    WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@title='Export to CSV']"))).click()

print(optionsList)
print(len(optionsList))
```

Answer (score 0):

To click on an option e.g. **(00002) CLP** and then to click on the <kbd>Search</kbd> button you to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.hkex.com.hk/eng/sorc/options/statistics_hv_iv.aspx")
  Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select#underlying")))).select_by_value("00002")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "td a[title='Search']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.hkex.com.hk/eng/sorc/options/statistics_hv_iv.aspx")
  Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='underlying']")))).select_by_value("00002")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td//a[@title='Search']"))).click()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: clickSearch]

- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```